# Xcode - find inheritance 'tree' for an object

Tags: swift, xcode, ide

Is there a way in Xcode to find out who implements or extends a given class or protocol?

ex.

```
class Car {
     ...
}
class GoCart {
    ...
}
extension Car: Drivable {
    ...
}
extension GoCart: Drivable {
    ...
}
protocol Drivable {
    func steer(vector: Point)
}
```

I would like to search for Drivable and get Car and GoCart, possibly in the symbol navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the approach I would have preferred, but searching in the Find Navigator using **Find > Text > Matching** with **Matching Case** enabled will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `is` keyword - i.e.:

```
switch car {
case car where car is GoCart:
case car where car is Drivable:
}

or you can try

if car is Drivable {

} else if car is GoCart {

}
```

Comment: This is an IDE question in this case.  I want to know how in Xcode I can find the inheritance "tree" of an object, either in the symbol navigator or as a search result.  It's not really a Swift question, I just used Swift as the example language.  Apologies if I tagged it incorrectly.